# Swift sort NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, nsarray

I have a problem with my sorting algorithm.

My `NSArray` (here `vcd.signals.key`) contains values of Strings for example:

```
"x [0]", "x [18]", "x [15]", "x [1]"...
```

When I try to sort this the result ends up in

```
"x [0]", "x [15]", "x [18]", "x [1]"
```

instead of:

```
"x [0]", "x [1]", "x [15]", "x [18]"
```

This is my code:

```
let sortedKeys = sorted(vcd.signals.keys) {
    var val1 = $0 as! String
    var val2 = $1 as! String

    return val1 < val2
 }
```

Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Your `x[0], x[18], x[15],...` there are `String` each one?

Comment: yes each of them are strings

Comment: Where are the strings? Can you put quotes round the actual strings please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem come associated with your comparison , for example see what happen when you compare the two following strings:

```
println("x [15]" < "x [1]") // true
```

This is because the default lexicography comparer goes character for character, position by position comparing ,and of course `5` in position 3 is less than `]` in position 3:

```
println("5" < "]") // true
```

For the explained above you need to create you own comparer but , only compare for the numbers inside the `[$0]`. For achieve this I use regular expressions to match any numbers inside the brackets like in the following way:

```
func matchesForRegexInText(regex: String!, text: String!) -> [String] {

    let regex = NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex,
        options: nil, error: nil)!
    let nsString = text as NSString
    let results = regex.matchesInString(text,
        options: nil, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        as! [NSTextCheckingResult]
    return map(results) { nsString.substringWithRange($0.range)}
}

var keysSorted = keys.sorted() {

        var key1 = $0
        var key2 = $1

        var pattern  = "([0-9]+)"   
        var m1 = self.matchesForRegexInText(pattern, text: key1)
        var m2 = self.matchesForRegexInText(pattern, text: key2)

        return  m1[0] < m2[0]
}
```

In the above regular expression I assume that the numbers only appears inside the brackets and match any number inside the `String`, but feel free to change the regular expression if you want to achieve anything more. Then you achieve the following:

```
println(keysSorted) // [x [0], x [1], x [15], x [18]]
```

I hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is the closing brace character ']' comes after digits. This means that "18" is less than "1]". As long as all your strings share the form of "[digits]" then you can remove the closing brace, sort the strings, add the closing brace back to your final array. The code below works for Swift 2:

```
let arr = ["x [0]", "x [18]", "x [15]", "x [1]"]
let sorted = arr.map { $0.substringToIndex($0.endIndex.predecessor()) }.sort().map { $0 + "]" }

print(sorted)
```